# how to use remove() in list in python when data exists as pair?

Tags: python

scores = [("Moe", 1000), ("Larry", 1500), ("Curly", 3000)]

Given is my list named `scores`.

I want to remove entry ("Moe", 1000) using `remove()` 
which I tried like `scores.remove(["Moe",1000])`
which gave an error

`ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list`

Though I was able to achieve it using del scores[0] but how can it be done using `remove()`. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You are asking how to remove a _tuple_ from a list

Comment: `scores.remove(("Moe", 1000))`? lists will never equal tuples.

Comment: Your call to `remove` gave a list as the target item; change that to a tuple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to remove a list value, but the value is actually a tuple.

```
scores.remove(("Moe",1000))
```

For troubleshooting:

```
help(scores.remove)
```

will show you the definition of `remove()`. It removes the first occurrence of the value.

```
for x in scores:
    type(x)
    x
```

This shows you each value and also the type of that value. From here, you could copy/paste that output into your remove function and it would work.

Answer (score 1):

The correct syntax is:

`scores.remove(("Moe", 1000))`

This is a **tuple**, so the delimiters are parentheses. Using brackets, the code will search for a **list**, which isn't your case.